# Should I declare my Swing components as instance variables, or just return them from functions?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, refactoring

I am just getting started with JAVA and I am trying to figure out what the best practice for declaring variables would be, esp in regards to GUI components. I am trying to keep my functions as small as possible, but I am not sure if I should declare all my components as instance variables for my GUI class.

In this code, I was thinking to only declare major parts of the gui, such as the frame, panel, menuBar and the menus themselves, but I am not sure which parts I should be declaring as instance variables and what parts should be encapsulated.

```
class MyClass {

    public JFrame frame;
    public JPanel panel;
    public JMenuBar menuBar;
    public JMenu fileMenu;
    public JMenu editMenu;

    ....
    public void setUpEditMenu() {
          editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
          editMenu.add(getEditMenuItem());
    }

    public JMenuItem getEditMenuItem() {
          JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Preferences");
          return menuItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: getEditMenuItem should be called createEditMenuItem and be declared private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most GUI Builders for Java (like Netbeans) declare GUI Components as instance variables.
There's actually no need to encapsulate them since you'll mostly want to access their already encapsulated properties!
Also don't forget about the overhead of excessive function calls.
In my opinion, don't over-encapsulate stuff. Your code will be much more complicated to use and rather cumbersome.

Comment: isn't there overhead from declaring all of that stuff? for example.. what if I had 1000 sub menu items. Doesn't that just make the code unreadable?

Comment: Making the code unreadable is different from overhead! Declaring properties does not create the kind of overhead I mentioned. They're using up memory to store their info. Cascaded function calls induce overhead because the system has to push some info on the system stack, call that, store new info and so on (If you have basic info about how a function is called in an OS, you'll know what I mean) Why doing something like this? ==> f1() => f2() => f3()... That's what I mean when I'm talking about overhead.